# Zip folder in GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am trying to zip a folder in GCP bucket using below command

`gsutil cp -z "*" gs://bucket_name/raw/data/ gs://bucket_name/raw/`

and i also tried this

`gsutil cp -z -r gs://bucket_name/raw/CASPR/ gs://bucket_name/raw/`

and this as well

`gsutil cp -z gs://bucket_name/raw/CASPR/ gs://bucket_name/raw/`

but nothing works, command is also not giving any exception niether any zi file creating in raw folder.

i also tried the destination as local folder as well, but same thing no zip file created

Comment: Could you confirm that after running the commands above you can see that the `Content-Encoding` for your objects is set to `gzip`? You can check it via the Cloud Storage UI, by selecting an object and then "Edit Metadata" or by running the `gsutil ls -l gs://<bucket-name>/<file-name>` command.

Comment: I dont have access to UI but when I ran command it doesnt show any content encoding

Comment: My bad, it should be capital **L**. Try this command instead: `gsutil ls -L gs://<bucket-name>/<file-name>`

Comment: there is no content encoding but 
Content-Type is  application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

The -z option is applied on the file [before the upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options). Thus you can't apply this on file on Cloud Storage. The parameter is ignore and all the file are copied without compression.

Copy first the file locally and then use the -z command.